# How to calculate the total of a single column in hana table

Tags: sapui5, hana

Is there a way to get the total sum of a column in hana db table, and use it in sapui5 app via odata or xsjs?

SQL console on hana db
[image]
XSJS Code I am trying

```
var query = "SELECT SUM(\"Schema_Name\".\"Table_Name\".\"Column_Name\")" + " AS TotalItemsOrdered FROM \"Schema_Name\".\"Table_Name\"";

var conn = $.db.getConnection();
//var pcall = conn.prepareCall(query);
var pcall = conn.prepareStatement(query);
pcall.execute();
var rs = pcall.getResultSet();
var output = {};

//Here you parse rs and put it to output
while (rs.next()) {
    output.total = rs.getString(1);
    output.results.push(output);
}
rs.close();
pcall.close();
conn.commit();
conn.close();
$.response.contentType = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
$.response.setBody(JSON.stringify(output));
$.response.status = $.net.http.OK;
```

Still not getting it. SQL statement is working fine in sql console, returning the sum. But not working in XSJS(any idea what's wrong on the code?

Answer (score 0):

You parse the result into a string? What for?

Also, what error messe do you receive?

For UI5 programming there are plenty examples in the developer guide. So if your question is that broad, better make sure you read up on the basics there.

BTW: in SQL you typically only make the full reference of tables in the FROM clause and use table aliases from thereon:

```
SELECT 
      SUM(tab1."Column_Name") AS "TotalItemsOrdered" 
FROM 
     "Schema_Name"."Table_Name" tab1;
```

And when you want to have your CamelCase-style column naming be preserved then you need to put it in double quotes.

Comment: Error is -  `500 - Internal server error
An error occurred during the processing of your request.
Data might be lost.` No special intention on parsing as a string(can parse it directly to output). Thank you for the SQL part.(being a newbee, trying out)  Got the sapui5 part covered.. Thank you @Lars Br.